# Windows 7 BSOD, unable to access system in normal mode

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

Lets summarize what I am facing:

- I face **BSODs** whenever I start my Laptop. Occurrence of BSODs increases with time and now it has literally reached infinity which means now I can't access my system in NORMAL MODE. I can only use **SAFE MODE**.
- Only hardware I have not changed is **Motherboard, daughter board** & **processor**.

**System Configuration:**

- Dell Inspiron 5010
- Windows 7 64bit - i3 M370 2.40GHz
- RAM DDR3-4GB
- ATI Radeon HD 4650 graphics - 1GB
  Also Updated the AMD Graphics driver to version 13.9

**Problem signature:**

Problem Event Name: BlueScreen

OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1

Locale ID: 1033

Additional information about the problem:

BCCode: 124

BCP1: 0000000000000000

BCP2: FFFFFA8004D1B028

BCP3: 00000000BE000000

BCP4: 0000000000800136

OS Version: 6_1_7601

Service Pack: 1_0

Product: 256_1

Now I am providing all the required files which might help to diagnose the issue with details.

1. Minidump (3 most recent) files
2. System Information
3. Event Viewer (System)
4. Speccy (Safe Mode)
5. Driver View (Safe Mode)

Link for the files :
https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArYR3y7fLJ3neNclfS-LHVPUhBo

It would be really great if we could resolve this issue asap.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) and using the [!errrec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563008.aspx) command shows that you have a Cache issue with your Intel i3 M370 CPU:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa8004d52028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000800152, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.23572.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.161011-0600

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Inspiron N5010

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  A15

BIOS_VENDOR:  Dell Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  A15

BIOS_DATE:  07/19/2011

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:        

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A15

2: kd> !errrec fffffa8004d52028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa8004d52028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d27498b7511103
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/22/2017 10:18:32 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004d520a8
Section       @ fffffa8004d52180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Instruction Execute
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000020655
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000004

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004d520f0
Section       @ fffffa8004d52240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000004
CPU Id        : 55 06 02 00 00 08 10 04 - bd e3 9a 00 ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa8004d52240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004d52138
Section       @ fffffa8004d522c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : ICACHEL2_IRD_ERR (Proc 2 Bank 6)
  Status      : 0xbe00000000800152
  Address     : 0x0000000002ae7a40
  Misc.       : 0x0000000004051301
```

This looks like a faulty CPU. The older CPUs should be socket based, so you can try to get a [used CPU from ebay](http://www.ebay.com/p/Intel-Core-i3-370M-2-4-GHz-Dual-Core-CP80617004119AL-Processor/109635767) and replace the CPU.

Comment: Well my system has i3 370 processor, don't know why you mentioned i5. And don't you think if the problem would have been with the processor then it should have crashed in safe mode as well.

Comment: this is a simple typo, come on! in safe mode less programs run that access the cache, so the system only seams to be working. But if you know everything better than I'll no longer help you. Bye, Bye.

Comment: Didn't mean to offend you. It was just a query. Could there be some other reason behind it, like faulty Graphics card as graphics drivers are not loaded in safe mode? I'll try if changing the processor helps. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: no, ICACHEL2_IRD_ERR looks like CPU L2 Cache issue. look for a BIOS update, make sure the CPU is not undervolted, also check the RAM for errors. if nothing helps, replace the CPU.

Comment: any update on the issue?